# Dual of $End_A(M)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb C$-algebra and an integral domain. Assume also $A$ is Gorenstein. Let $M$ be a finitely generated torsion-free $A$ module.
Is it true that $Hom_A(End_A(M), A)\cong End_A(M)$?

Comment: What's the intuition behind this you suggest? What makes you suspect this?

Comment: If M is free then this is true ..so i was wondering under what condition this is true for other modules?

Comment: You clearly don't mean "=", since the two sides of the equality are sets of functions with different domains and codomains. Could you clarify what you do mean?

Comment: yes i meant "$\cong$"

Comment: I found that if $M$ is _dualisable_, which turns to be equivalent to be finitely presented and projective, then you have that $Hom(M,N) \simeq M^* \otimes N$. this case, the dual of $End(M)\simeq M^* \otimes M $ is $M^{**} \otimes M \simeq M \otimes M^* \simeq End(M)$, still because of dualisability. In case of gorentein rings, in particular they are noetherian, so that if I remember correctly finitely generate implies finitely presented. So I think that to find a counterexample you should search for a fgen which is torsion free but not projective (not flat is enough).

Comment: I see ..so you are saying that every sheaf which is not locally free sheaf should work as a counterexample.

Comment: I think I found that generally finitely generated torsion free modules over a domain are self dual - which would imply the statement here. I'll post a proof later!

Comment: oh that would be wonderful...i think we have to define some sort of Trace map and show that it is non-degenerate

Comment: Using a two-term free resolution $F_1\to F_0\to M$, we can write $\mathrm{End}_A(M)$ as the (middle) cohomology of a complex $\mathrm{Hom}(F_0,F_1)\to\mathrm{Hom}(F_0,F_0)\oplus\mathrm{Hom}(F_1,F_1)\to\mathrm{Hom}(F_1,F_0)$. This should lead to a proof since we know what the dual of this complex is.

Comment: THe previous comment by me is missing a term. The first term of the complex should include $\{g\in\mathrm{Hom}(F_1,F_1)| d\circ g=9\}$. So it does not lead to a proof.

Comment: Eheheh as you guess, I found a flaw while I was writing the proof down. Hope I will manage to correct it!

Comment: If $M$ is not reflexive, this is false. As an example, take $M=A\oplus I$ where $A=k[x,y]$, $I=(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mohan mentioned in the comments, this is false if one does not assume $M$ is reflexive, but $M$ being reflexive is still not good enough. I'll comment on the local case, and remark that this can easily be extended to more generality, including, for instance, the standard graded case.

> **Proposition**: Let $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a Gorenstein local ring with $\dim A \le 1$. If $\operatorname{Hom}_A(\operatorname{End}_A(\mathfrak{m}),A) \cong \operatorname{End}_A(\mathfrak{m})$, then $\mu_A(\mathfrak{m}) \le 2$.
>
> Proof: Let $(-)^*=\operatorname{Hom}_A(-,A)$ denote the $A$-dual.  Then, as $A$-modules, we have $\operatorname{End}_A(\mathfrak{m}) \cong \mathfrak{m}^*$ (see, for example, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178803)).  Furthermore, since $\dim A \le 1$, $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay, and thus reflexive, since $A$ is Gorenstein. In particular, we have $\operatorname{End}_A(\mathfrak{m})^* \cong \mathfrak{m}^{**} \cong \mathfrak{m}$.  We claim that if $\mathfrak{m} \cong \mathfrak{m}^*$, then $\mu_A(\mathfrak{m}) \le 2$.  To see this, we have the natural exact sequence $0 \to \mathfrak{m} \to A \to k \to 0$.  Applying $(-)^*$ to this sequence, we get an exact sequence of the form
> $$ 0 \to k^* \to A^* \to \mathfrak{m}^* \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(k,A) \to 0.$$  Either $\dim A=0$ or $\dim A=1$.  If $\dim A=0$, then, as $A$ is Gorenstein, $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(k,A)=0$, so so we have a surjection $A \to \mathfrak{m}$, implying $\mu_A(\mathfrak{m}) \le 1$.  In instead, $\dim A=1$, then $k^*=0$ and $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(k,A) \cong k$; of course $A^* \cong A$.  In particular, $\mu_A(\mathfrak{m}) \le \mu_A(A)+\mu_A(k)=2$.  As a remark, note that in the dimension $1$ case we actually have the stronger claim that the Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity $e(A)$ of $A$ is at most $2$; I'll leave this as an exercise.

To point out, some work has been done on understanding for which local rings every maximal Cohen-Macaulay module is self dual, rather than endomorphism modules; see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404995000135) which also contains part of the above Proposition, though the argument is slightly different and a bit more general.  This condition is extremely restrictive (for instance it forces $A$ to be a hypersurface and it is conjectured that $e(A) \le 2$ without the $\dim A \le 1$ hypothesis), and I would expect the same of the condition that $\operatorname{End}_A(M)$ be self dual for even every maximal Cohen-Macaulay $M$.